# MonoTouch/Three20: Add many items to the first page of TTLauncherView

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, three20

I observed some unexpected behavior with TTLauncherView from Three20.

After creating a standard view like this
`var launcher = new Three20.TTLauncherView();`

If I try to add `TTLauncherItem`items like this

```
launcher.AddItem(item1, false);
launcher.AddItem(item2, false);
```

it creates a new page for each items.

Reading [some Objective-C sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367161/856403) I came across something that would translate like this in C#, but it doesn't work neither, due to a `System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.IsNewRefcountEnabled'` at runtime.

```
var items = NSArray.FromObjects(NSArray.FromObjects (item1, item2));
launcher.Pages = items;
```

So how would one go about adding many items to the first page of an `TTLauncherView` with MonoTouch using the official Three20 bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.IsNewRefcountEnabled

This error comes from bindings compiled with MonoTouch 5.1+ where a new refcount mode is available.

If you're using MonoTouch 5.0.x (latest stable) then you'll need to rebuild the **Three20** bindings library to use them in your project.

Otherwise you can update to the latest MonoTouch (5.2.1) beta to use the binding binaries you already have. A stable release should be available soon so using the beta for a short term might be easier for you (than rebuilding the bindings).

Comment: Recompiled the bindings and everything is working fine now. Thanks. (Still not a very nice API to deal with though)